# Сделать универсальный селектор для id содержащих строки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вида pay_online_ru, pay_online_it, pay_online_fr и тд. К ним всем нужно применить maxlength. Как можно это сделать явно не перечисляя их все?

```
$("input[id*='pay_online_, clear_cart_, back_to_shop_, pay_cash_, your_cart_, checkout_']").maxlength({
...
});
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужен [селектор начала строки](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-substrings): `input[id^='pay_online_']`.

Comment: Как в моем случае его использовать? input[id^='pay_online_, clear_cart_', ...] или input[id^='pay_online_'], input[id^='clear_cart_'], .... ?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, можно `'input:is([id^="pay_online_"], [id^="clear_cart_"])'`.